# Option Menu Button Code getting Stuck and Hanging

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling to see why my code is not getting into the try statement after I hit the NearBy button on the options menu.  It goes to a black screen but the IN NEAR CASE string doesn't display in the output of the logcat in Eclipse or in aLogCat on an Android phone?  What am I doing wrong?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {

private static final int NEAR = Menu.FIRST;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, NEAR, 0, "NearBy").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case NEAR:
       try {
           Log.e(LOG_TAG,"IN NEAR CASE");
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,
                      AndroidClient.class);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Value Age is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect your app to do? The code that you posted compiles fine.

Do you want to start AndroidClient? Add this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, AndroidClient.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

As a note you don't have an onCreate() method so the screen will always be blank, unless you load a layout with setContentView(). (I'm guessing that this is a shortened version of your app, but I wanted to be thorough.)